# Angular 9 input date

Tags: javascript, angular

I try to figure out, why attribute value on input type date not working with Angular 9.

```
<input type="date" [max]="dateConfig.max" [min]="dateConfig.min" name="date" [value]="dateConfig.value" />
```

In the date-picker component I have:

```
export class DatePickerComponent implements OnInit {

  private defaultMinDate: Date = new Date(-8.64e15);
  private defaultMaxDate: Date = new Date(8.64e15);

  dateConfig = {
    min: this.defaultMinDate,
    max: this.defaultMaxDate,
    value: new Date()


 }
}
```

When I run the code, date picker show me an input with no initial value.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An HTML date input value should be in the format yyy-mm-dd, otherwise it will not show a value.

You can use pipe for example: "dateConfig.value | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'"  or new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10) in TS file

Comment: Thank you so much! I forgot something important!